# Authenticating to Azure Resource Manager with a Service Principal in Azure Automation

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-resource-manager

So there's now a [documented workaround](https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/07/14/using-azure-resource-manager-in-azure-automation-runbooks/) to use ARM in Azure Automation, and it's also [well documented](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/27/azure-automation-authenticating-to-azure-using-azure-active-directory/) how to authenticate to ARM using a Service Principal.  But even after following these steps I still cannot get the combination of those to work.  Running my runbook in Automation with a Service Principal always gives the following error:

```
New-AzureTag : Your Azure credentials have not been set up or have expired, please run Add-AzureAccount to set up your 
Azure credentials.
At Add-SubscriptionTags:48 char:48
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureTag], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Tags.Tag.NewAzureTagCommand
```

`Add-AzureAccount` and `Select-AzureSubscription` both execute fine, but when I call any cmdlet to actually do something I get the above error.

My runbook works when I use a regular AAD org account, so I don't think it's an Automation/ARM issue.

Running my workflow on my PC with the service principal also works, so I think my service principal is set up correctly.

Has anyone successfully implemented this scenario?

Comment: I also messed around with calling `Add-AzureAccount` twice and using AzureProfiles based on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/362), but no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a bug in Azure PowerShell. It has been identified and there is a work item to fix it. I will add the GitHub issue if I'm able to find it.

**Update:** Here's the GitHub issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/655

Comment: Also, unless that PS fix is going to be out very shortly, it might be worth documenting the limitation in your [blog post](https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/07/14/using-azure-resource-manager-in-azure-automation-runbooks/), which sort of implies that a service principal will work.